# How to add a legend to an amCharts column chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'd like to add a legend to a column chart, but it is not working as expected.

What I do is simply adding

```
"legend" : {}
```

to the chart. Apart from being a technical requirement in my project, the legend would allow me to hide individual columns by clicking the appropriate marker.
Can anyone help?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhpy49h8/1/

Comment: You are forgetting the plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/67vxvLpc/

Comment: Thanks. I can't help feeling that this is a workaround, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

```
"legend":{
  "useGraphSettings": true}
```

> for more options visit [its own web site](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend)

Comment: If you have a look at my JSFiddle, you'll see that this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = 'bottom';
chart.legend.fontSize = 9;
chart.legend.dy = 14;
chart.legend.scrollable = true;
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.clickable = false;
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.focusable = false;
chart.legend.data = [
    {"name":'Asia',"fill":'red'},
  {"name":'North America',"fill":'blue'},
  {"name":'Africa',"fill":'green'}
];
```

Comment: I appreciate the code snippet you've provided. However, to make your answer more valuable, could you please accompany it with an explanation of how the code works and how it specifically addresses the question's issue? This additional context would greatly enhance the clarity and educational value of your response, helping both the original asker and future readers understand the solution better. 
Please read following guide: 
[How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can create own legend as your requirement. you can check below link for more detail. i have created own legend. [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/amantandon1/09d3f8cr/33/)